# What is the iOS 8 System Font?

Tags: fonts, ios8, font-face, typography

What is the iOS 8 System Font?

It looks like it's no longer Helvetica Neue and a search does not yield any definitive results that identifies the iOS 8 font - although some speculate it's an Apple custom [Myriad](https://news.layervault.com/stories/24712-ask-dn-what-font-did-apple-use-on-the-ios-8-banner-at-moscone-west).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816828/what-is-the-name-of-the-slim-system-font-in-ios-7

Comment: that question does not cover iOS8, nor does the site linked in the question

Answer (score 7):

Signs point to Helvetica Neue being the default system font for iOS8.

source: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-system-font-in-iOS-8

Answer (score -3):

I think it may me the new font they developed for the apple watch. It is called San Francisco.

http://www.fastcodesign.com/3038794/fast-feed/apple-releases-its-most-important-typeface-in-20-years

[image]

Comment: San Francisco is the font for iOS 9.