# Which font / font size is used by apple for the placeholder in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I try to clone a placeholder behavior for a tableCell. It must look exactly like the placeholder used within a UITextField. Does anybody know which Font is used by Apple as well as which Font size?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the name of the slim system font in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816828/what-is-the-name-of-the-slim-system-font-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font in UITextfield is HelveticaNeue 14